# Leading from the wrong (nondummy) hand in bridge

Tags: bridge

While playing bridge you were supposed to lead from the dummy's hand, but you pulled a card from your hand by mistake. After putting it back in your hand, do you have to play the same suit when you play from the dummy hand?

Answer (score 6):

From the [Laws of Contract Bridge - 2014](http://www.acbl.org/acbl-content/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Laws-of-Contract-Bridge1.pdf),

**Law 55 - Declarer's Lead Out of Turn**

> When declarer leads out of turn from his or dummy's hand:
>   A either defender, without consultation, may accept that lead as provided in Law 53; or
>   B. either defender, without consultation, may require declarer to retract that lead. Then,
>    1. if it was a defender' turn to lead, declarer restores the card led in error to his or dummy's hand without penalty.
>    2. if declarer has led from the wrong hand when it was his turn to lead from his or dummy's hand, he withdraws the card led in error and he must lead a card from the correct hand.
>
> If declarer adopts a line of play that could have been based on information obtained through his infraction, the offenders should adjust the score to redress the damage.

So, in direct answer to your question, and assuming no inappropriate information was obtained by declarer through the infraction, once a defender requires declarer to retract the card led in error declarer restores it without penalty and leads (any card of his choice) from the correct hand.

In a club (other than a Duplicate Club) a slightly more formal alternative law may apply using the services of a pre-appointed *Arbiter*, if such is available. I understand from your description that this is not the case fr your question.

Answer (score 0):

In the shortened version:

- No, they cannot force you to lead from the same suit in the hand that should have led. But they can "accept" your lead from the wrong hand (or reject it). If the next player plays, that is assumed as an acceptance (whether that player was alert or not about the play out of turn).

Declarer should not draw an "inference" from the opponents willingness or not to accept the lead.

In general, there is no "damage" to the opponents because your partner is dummy and cannot gain any advantage by knowing about you holding a certain card.